# Using call read within a js function

Tags: karate

I have a slight problem I want to solve. I have the following lines of code which create 2 users which works. However the issue is that, it creates both users with the same Id from the the first line of code:

- def myId = call read('classpath:karate/helpers/guid.js')
- def users = function(){ karate.call('classpath:v1/api_CreateUser.feature')}
- def usersResult = karate.repeat(2, users )

So I want to be able to create multiple users with different Ids. I tried the following:

## * def users =

```
    """
    function(){
        var myId = null;
        if(myId == null)
        {
          myId = call read('classpath:karate/helpers/guid.js')
        }
        karate.call('classpath:v1/api_CreateUser.feature');
    }
    """
```

- def usersResult = karate.repeat(2, users )

So the idea is to reset the 'myId' variable everytime to null, check if null which will be true, then call the js function which generates the id and assign the result to 'myId' variable.
Then the variable will be used on the  karate.call('classpath:v1/api_CreateUser.feature') line.

Unfortunately I'm getting  javascript evaluation failed error.

Anyone could help?

Thanks

Comment: I thought by voting it up would have set it as accepted, my bad. Answer has been accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be clear about the slight difference when you are in Karate and when you are in JS. For example:

```
myId = call read('classpath:karate/helpers/guid.js')
```

This won't work. What you are looking for is:

```
myId = karate.call('classpath:karate/helpers/guid.js');
```

I recommend you read and understand the section on [Karate Expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions) it will save you a lot of trouble later.

When you use a JS function (that works) you should never need to worry about what you are. Just invoke it wherever, and it will "dispense" a new value. For example if you have:

```
* def time = function(){ return java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() + '' }
* def first = time()
* def second = time()
```

Here `first` and `second` will always be different. I think now you have all you need. You are trying to access a JS variable defined in Karate from within a function, this depends on *when* either was initialized and I don't recommend it if you don't know what you are doing. But if you want to access the *latest* value of a Karate variable, the right way is to use [`karate.get(varNameAsString)`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-gethttps://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-get).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will read and understand more the karate expressions.